# Counter module and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

In a previous exercise, I've written a code that printed the height of each mountains of a csv file. You can found it here:

```
import csv

def mountain_height(filename):
    """ Read in a csv file of mountain names and heights.  
    Parse the lines and print the names and heights. 
    Return the data as a dictionary. 
    The key is the mountain and the height is the value.
    """

    mountains = dict()
    msg = "The height of {} is {} meters."
    err_msg = "Error: File doesn't exist or is unreadable."

    # TYPE YOUR CODE HERE.
    try:
        with open('mountains.csv', 'r') as handle:
            reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter=',')

            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                height = row[1]
                mountains[name] = int(height)

            for name, height in mountains.items():
                print("The height of {names} is {heights} meters.".format(names=name, heights=height))

    except:
        print("Error: Something wrong with your file location?")
        return None
```

I'm not sure if its ideal, but it seems to work.

Here's a preview of the csv file:
[mountains.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izazc.png)

Now, I have to rewrite this code using the collections' module Counter, to count how many times each mountain range is mentioned. Each row contains a mountain, its height, and the range it is part of.

I also need to add a dictionary that records all the heights of the mountains in a particular range. I must use a list for the values of the heights. The key will be the range name. Each time there's a new mountain in the range, the height has to be added to the list for that key. For example, after reading all the data, mountains['Himalayas'] == [8848, 8586, 8516, 8485, 8201, 8167, 8163, 8126, 8091, 8027]. (The "Himalayas" are the range.)

The output should be to print the top 2 ranges and adding the range name to the counter. 
Then, print the average height of the mountains in each range. Return the dictionary object with the ranges and their lists of mountain heights after all the printing.

I have very small notions of the Counter module and I feel overwhelmed by the task.
Do you have some advice on where to start ?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean
def mountain_ranges(filename):
    ranges = Counter()
    heights = defaultdict(list)
```

Thank you in advance....

Comment: Can you please show sample CSV and expected data

Comment: Why do you "have" to use the `Counter`?

Comment: I think this more an issue of problem solving strategy in general? Think about how you would do it "by hand", identify groupable steps in the workflow (subtasks), and lookup whether some predefined lib can help you with some of the steps (like Counter here). divide et impera...

Comment: @Alderven I've added a link to a preview of the CSV file in the post, hope it helps!

Comment: @PyPingu I have to use it because it is a requirement for data extraction exercice within an internet course I am following. However, I never used it before and I am still at the beginning of my course, and a bit lost...

Comment: @jerch indeed I think it is mainly due to a problem solving issue, but not knowing how to use the Counter module is blocking me in my reflection process... thanks for the advice!

Comment: Can you please also show expected output?

Comment: @Alderven I think the final output is to print 1) the top 2 ranges (3rd column of csv) according to their counter value, with the range name and 2) print the average height of the mountains in each range

Answer (score 0):

The following will print out what you asked for, and return the counter and dictionary of heights.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from statistics import mean


def mountain_height(filename):
    """ Read in a csv file of mountain names and heights.  
    Parse the lines and print the names and heights. 
    Return the data as a dictionary. 
    The key is the mountain and the height is the value.
    """
    range_heights = defaultdict(list)
    range_count = Counter()
    # TYPE YOUR CODE HERE.
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
            reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    name = row[0]
                    height = row[1]
                    mrange = row[2]
                    range_heights[mrange].append(int(height))
                    range_count[mrange] += 1
    except:
        print("Error: Something wrong with your file location?")
        return None

    print("The 2 most frequent ranges are:")
    for mrange in range_count.most_common(2):
        print(f"{mrange[0]} has {mrange[1]} mountains")
    print("The average heights of each range are:")
    for mrange, heights in range_heights.items():
        print(f"{mrange} -- {mean(heights)}m")

    return range_count, range_heights


counts, heights = mountain_height('mountains.csv')


The 2 most frequent ranges are:
Himalayas has 10 mountains
Karakoram has 4 mountains
The average heights of each range are:
Himalayas -- 8321m
Karakoram -- 8194.25m
```

So you know, I don't personally believe that using a `Counter` here is necessary or the "right" way to do things, but since it's what you require it's what I've given you. In fact it isn't even the only way you could use a `Counter` here - you could create a list of each range as you loop through the rows, and then just apply the `Counter(list_of_ranges)` but for larger files that would mean creating a large list in memory which again seems pointless.

For clarity my personal solution to getting the counts without a `Counter` would be to just use the `range_heights` dictionary and dict comprehension like so:

`range_counts = {r: len(heights) for r, heights in range_heights.items()}`

Comment: Imho posting a c&p solution is not very helpful here, also your thoughts about memory consumption / optimization misses the goal - it seems the OP should learn how to utilize ready-to-go bits and pieces.

Comment: I could have just linked to the docs on `Counter` but I was feeling charitable, so I’ve basically just inserted the example from the docs into the OPs code.

Comment: PyPingu's answer was helpful in the sense that I now understand how the use of 'Counter' is not the most efficient here. I now need to print the heights of each mountains in a range in a list, and I can now try to do this by my own as I have the base ! Thanks PyPingu ;)